# Spring test load bean configuration from XML and annotation both?

Tags: spring, junit, dependency-injection, spring-test

Here is my Spring Junit

```
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration({"classpath*:/META-INF/spring/*.xml" ,
             "classpath*:META-INF/spring/datasource-testcontext.xml"})

    @TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
            DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class })
    public class GenericDaoTest {

        @Test
        public void testFind() throws Exception {

        }

          @Configuration
          @ComponentScan("com.myComp.user")
          public static class SpringConfig {

          }
```

But still it is not able to find `com.myComp.user.UserDAO` which is annotated with `@Component`. Not sure what I am missing here ?

Below is the exception I am getting

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.myComp.user.UserDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot declare both `@Configuration` classes *and* XML configuration files simultaneously.

You have to pick one of those formats and then *import* the other.

One option would be to get rid of your static nested `@Configuration` class and simply configure component scanning within a declared XML configuration file.

Another option would be to import the XML config via your `@Configuration` class as follows.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@TestExecutionListeners({
    DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class
})
public class GenericDaoTest {

    @Test
    public void testFind() {
    }

    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan("com.myComp.user")
    @ImportResource({
        "classpath*:/META-INF/spring/*.xml",
        "classpath*:META-INF/spring/datasource-testcontext.xml"
    })
    public static class SpringConfig {
    }

}
```